# 100% TextArea in FireFox using absolute position

Tags: html, textarea, css-position

I'm trying to make my `textarea` to fill all available space, I used:

I can't use 100% `width` & `height` as I have margins & paddings all over the place, I have to use absolute position within relative position parent + `top`, `right`, `bottom` & `left` all 0 - which doesn't work in FF. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Update 1 - when I replace my `textarea` with  `DIV` it starts working.

Update 2 - Actual markup:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: relative; margin: 25px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: Gray;">
        <textarea style="top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;">A</textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **please** show us some code. we're **hungry**.

Comment: the post is updated. Check it in Chro-Chro and then in FF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mr Snook failed back in march last year, but he suggested a way you could solve it:

> [wrap the textarea in another element](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/absolute-position-textarea)

Does this in any way help you?