# make TextBox field cover the parent div, should be cross browser

Tags: asp.net, html, css, cross-browser

In the below code, the TextBox field should fit the Width and Height of the `div#chat-message`(with a gap of `2px`) which could be seen as perfect in Chrome but not in IE8 or Mozilla. In Mozilla, the TextBox field can also be resized which I dont want to happen.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Nested in Div's -->
 <div id="chat-message-outline">
    <div id="chat-message">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtmsg" BackColor="Transparent" runat="server"
                  Wrap="true" BorderStyle="None" TextMode="MultiLine" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#chat-message-outline
{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
  position: relative;
}

#chat-message, #txtmsg
{
  padding: 0;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  resize: none; /* CSS3 property */
}
```

Please assist me to make this code Cross-browser..

Edit: I cant use percentages because I need `2px` gap between the TextBox field and the parent div.

PS: I asked this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13506949/1577396) before to which I got answer which is not cross-browser (realised later)

Answer (score 1):

A solution how to fit textarea in another element using `position:absolute`: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/absolute-position-textarea

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bQQYA/
EDIT: Fiddle with 2px spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/3EPSL/

Also, I've found similar question: [100% TextArea in FireFox using absolute position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756087/100-textarea-in-firefox-using-absolute-position)

Comment: Thank you for response, actually I want to have the 2px gap between the parent div and the Textbox field. which is not possible with percentages. check my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13506949/1577396)

Comment: It was caused by added border to `<textarea>`. Please see updated fiddle (textarea without borders) here: http://jsfiddle.net/3EPSL/
Is this the result you need?

Comment: This still doesn't work.. check my previous question which I kept in my post. The problem is what if the parent div is NESTED in another div.

Comment: +1 It seems working fine. Right now I dont have other browsers installed(I am at office,chrome & IE) I will check at home. Thank you for showing great effort. :)